# Normal distributions and probability

Tags: probability

I'm tasked with finding P(X>130) for a given distribution. I know that

P(X > 130) = 1 − Φ(

(130 − µ)/
σ)

where Φ is the normal distribution.

What I'm wondering is, the only mean and standard deviations I have to work with are ones I have from a given data set that correlates (not completely) to a normal distribution. Am I supposed to use the mean and standard deviation of that data set?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The answer is likely: yes, use the mean and standard deviation from your data set. However, if you are in a junior or senior level undergraduate statistics course, you may be required to do something more complicated including statistical estimation. Are you sure X isn't a sample mean here? The question would make more sense then, as you'd be using the sampling distribution of the sample mean. Also, it could be that at distribution is involved if you aren't supposed to assume the data standard deviation is that of the population.